# Intermittent failure running arquillian tests

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I am running arquillian tests on Red Hat EAP 6.4 (JBoss AS 7) but I am getting intermittent failures. About half of the time, everything runs through to the end as expected. The other half of the time I notice that "arquillian-service" does not get deployed to the app server, which results in the following error when the war is deployed:

```
{"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.myapp.war\".main is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.arquillian-service\".main, module.resolved.service.\"deployment.myapp.war\".main]",
"jboss.module.resolve.phase.\"deployment.myapp.war\".main.1 is missing [jboss.module.spec.service.\"deployment.arquillian-service\".main]"]}
```

Environment

- Windows 7
- EAP 6.4 running in a docker container
- Oracle Java 1.8

Relevant Dependencies (Arquillian container version 7.2.0.Final)

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
      <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<arquillian xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

  <container qualifier="jboss-remote" default="true">
    <configuration>
      <property name="managementAddress">${jboss.host}</property>
      <property name="username">${jboss.admin.user}</property>
      <property name="password">${jboss.admin.password}</property>

      <!-- Management port must be 9999 -->
      <property name="managementPort">9999</property>
    </configuration>
    <protocol type="Servlet 3.0">
      <property name="host">${jboss.host}</property>
      <property name="port">${jboss.host.port}</property>
    </protocol>

  </container>

</arquillian>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue on Windows, I haven't been able to reproduce it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

in your list of relevant dependencies, there isn't the most important dependency:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
</dependency>`

didn't you forget to add it there?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is there